# How to use classes in C++?

Tags: c++, class

I can't see to find the problem in my code. Nor the solution on the internet. I can see that i can create the code in a different way but i need to know how to work with it written like this:

```
class Triunghi{
    int l1=0;//latura1
    int l2=0;//latura2
    int ba=0;//baza
    int p=0;//perimetru
public:
    Triunghi(){}
    Triunghi(int a):l1(a){}
    Triunghi(int a,int b):l1(a),l2(b){}
    Triunghi(int a,int b,int c):l1(a),l2(b),ba(c){}
    Triunghi(int a,int b,int c,char *msg):l1(a),l2(b),ba(c){
        cout<<msg<<""<<l1<<l2<<ba<<endl;
    }
    Triunghi(Triunghi &A){
    l1=A.l1;
    l2=A.l2;
    ba=A.ba;
    }
    ~Triunghi(){
    }
    int Perimetru()
    {
        p=l1+l2+ba;
        return (p);
    }
};
```

It works fine there are no errors but i cant seem to give value to l1, l2 and ba, to use them in function 'Perimetru'.
This is how my main looks.

```
int main()
{
    Triunghi tri;
    Triunghi(1,2,3);
    tri.Perimetru();
    return 0;
}
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Are you wondering why nothing is printed? The `Triunghi(int a,int b,int c,char *msg)` overload is never called in your code.

Comment: Do a bit of exploratory programming. Make every call print out a "here at line x" message and try to understand your program's control flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Triunghi tri;
Triunghi(1,2,3);
```

This doesn't do what you think it does. `tri` is created with default constructor, so all of your members are set with their in-class default values, meaning `0`. Then, you create temporary object `Triunghi`, and you don't even use it. What you might wanted to do instead is:

```
Triunghi tri(1,2,3);
```

Then `Perimetru()` returns `6` as expected.